# Network Analyst REST service gives error "Routing error: Unable to complete operation unable to find attribute invalid Context"

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, network-analyst, silverlight

I have created an Network Analyst Routing sample. On Arcmap it works fine when creating a route on the data.

However, when I create Network Analyst service through ArcGIS Server, using this [REST service Silverlight sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#Routing) gives this error:

`Routing error: Unable to complete operation unable to find attribute invalid Context`

Any help please.

Comment: I have the same error. If you find anything out post back here or on:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/80708-Route-Task-Error?p=284199#post284199 thanks. i've been working on this one for days.....

Comment: Is the [Network Analyst for ArcGIS Server extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/network-extension) licensed on your server?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer Yes the Network Analyst for ArcGIS Server extension is licensed, and finally I found a solution using Geoprocessing task.

Answer (score 1):

i have made a model using model builder like [described here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/GP_service_example_Shortest_route_on_a_street_network/002v0000001q000000/)  , then i published the model on arcgis server, before calling it using silverlight.

Comment: Was this supposed to be a comment, or did it solve your issue?

Comment: i think this answer had solved her issue

Comment: i have solved this problem using geoprocessing task

Answer (score 1):

come across and solved the problem just now
cause **RouteParameters** 's default value of **UseHierarchy is True**
just set **UseHierarchy** to **False**

```
RouteParameters parameters = new RouteParameters();
parameters.Stops = stopsGraphicsLayer;
parameters.OutSpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;
parameters.UseHierarchy = false;
routeTask.SolveAsync(parameters);
```